# Pandas DataFrame.astype Error:long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'instancemethod'

Tags: python, pandas

I encountered an error after running the following code in python:

```
train_df['Fare'] = train_df['Fare'].astype(np.int)
```

In above line, `train_df` is a pandas DataFrame. And the error that I ran into was showed as

> long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'instancemethod'

I have looked up the panda's Doc but it didn't get me anywhere.I hope someone has encountered and solved this error before could maybe give an answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did the error happen in the same line of code?

Comment: This worked for me in python 2 and 3 across two versions of pandas. What does the data of the Fare column look like?

Comment: My version of python is 2.7.11 and the information of Fare colum is  "Fare        891 non-null float64"

Comment: What does the "Fare 891 non-null float64" mean? How did you determine that?

Comment: @DYZ I can not understand you ... This code occupies a single line in my codes

Comment: What did you type to see "Fare 891 non-null float64"?

Comment: @3novak By using DataFrame.info() . In my codes is train_df.info()

Comment: Could you show us the first few rows of your data?

Comment: Can you show the complete error message please?

Comment: @3novak@DYZ Thanks  a lot.I have found my error.I wrote down one line of code like "test_df['Fare'].fillna(value=test_df['Fare'].median,inplace=True)" .which test_df['Fare'].median should be test_df['Fare'].median().The code run without any information so I think there's no error in my previous codes.This is my first time to ask question in stack overflow  due to my poor English,but I'm still exited that I can communicate with you,HAHA!